# Error when use "http" on query string PHP

Tags: php, query-string

when i use an **http://**foo string on my page, i get error.

For example:

```
http://www.myadress.com/process.php?url=http://foo
```

When i cut http:// , it works. What must i do to use http:// on query strings?

i use url like this:

```
$address = @$_GET['url'];
$source = file_get_contents($url);
//bla bla
```

it displays **404** error.

No change with encode.

Always redirect to 404 error page. But when i erase http:// , it works. I wonder if it is because of .htaccess file?

**here are .htaccess codes (wordpress classic):**

```
RewriteEngine Off
#test
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Use PHP 5.3
Action application/x-hg-php53 /cgi-sys/php53
AddHandler application/x-hg-php53 .php
```

Comment: **What error do you get?**  Where are you using that URL?

Comment: what about encoding the `url` content? like http://www.myadress.com/process.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Ffoo

Comment: You're abusing `file_get_contents`. Never use user-supplied input directly in such functions.

Comment: it is not about abusing file_get_contents. Error is before that.

Answer (score 4):

As with all special characters in URLs, you have to [encode](http://php.net/urlencode) them.

Comment: No change. 

This works in another server but doesn't work in a server hosted by hostgator. So strange.

Comment: IIRC HostGator servers come with mod_security or something like that set up.  It's possible that it's set up to protect you from yourself, by preventing full URLs from getting passed to scripts.  (Some people just `include` the URL directly.  It's a way-too-common vulnerability that allows attackers to run arbitrary code on your server.)

Answer (score 4):

Depending on its contents, you may need to encode it with [`urlencode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.urlencode.php)

```
$url = urlencode("http://foo");
echo "http://www.example.com/process.php?url=$url;

// prints 
http://www.example.com/process.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Ffoo
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to replace the slashes with `%2F`, like this:
`http://www.myadress.com/process.php?url=http:%2F%2Ffoo`
Then PHP will convert it back to `http://`:
`echo $_GET["url"]; // echos http://foo`

Comment: No change with encode.

Always redirect to 404 error page. But i erase http:// , it works. I wonder if it is because of .htaccess file?

Comment: The slashes are fine.  It's the colon that's causing issues -- it's a special character in URLs, while slashes really aren't unless they're doubled up right after the first colon.

Comment: And no, it's not due to the .htaccess file; there's nothing in there that'd be causing the issue (assuming you posted the whole thing).  It might have something to do with your mod_security configuration, though, if escaping the URL doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If the http seems to be problem try something like this:

```
some.php?url=[s]something.com
```

And then use php

```
$url = str_replace("[s]", "http://", $url);
$source = file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: There's an already-designed solution to this problem (URL escape sequences), that lets you pass the real URL through.  Mangling the string like you suggest makes it so that it's only useful after a `str_replace`.  It's an ugly and error-prone solution to the problem.

Comment: @cHao,

there is not already-designed solution for "this" question.

Comment: @Benjamin if this works, maybe you can use this solution. Actually it´s not very handy, but at least it works!

Comment: If this does indeed work for you, then you could pass the URL as "something.com" and prepend the "http://" when retrieving it.

Answer (score 0):

Your web hosting provider, HostGator, rejects requests where the query string contains `http:/` for security reasons. For more information, see [this](http://forums.hostgator.com/mod-security-and-403-errors-t71394.html) thread. To get around this use partial URLs, put the URL in the hash, apply some sort of encoding, or make the request a POST request and put the URL in the body.